# What are the eigenvalues of this symmetric matrix?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 & 4 \\ 2 & 0 & 2 \\ 4 & 2 & 3  \end{pmatrix}.$$

I'm trying to find the eigenvalues of $A$, but when I calculate the characteristic polynomial, I get
$$p(\lambda)=-\lambda^3+6\lambda^2+15\lambda+2,$$
and I don't know how to solve $p(\lambda)=0$.
I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made an error in your CP, it should be:

$$p(\lambda)=-\lambda^3+6\lambda^2+15\lambda+8 = -(\lambda-8)(\lambda+1)^2 = 0$$

So you have the two eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = 8$ (single root) and $\lambda_{2,3} = -1$ (double root).

Can you continue with the eigenvectors now?

Comment: Nice catch (the error)! +1

Comment: I'm glad to hear you're well enough to go to the gym and hike!

Comment: Just take it easy on the hike. Dr. Amy's orders!

Comment: @amWhy: okay Doc! :-)